# Having issue with testing "backlog" as per ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)

Tags: java, serversocket

As per [ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int,%20int)), `backlog` indicates maximum length of the queue.

I created a simple server socket, with `backlog` as 1 using following code `ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8001, 1);` and my expectation was that when I will try to connect to this server with more than 1 client then I will get connection refused exception.

But when I tried to connect with this server from more than 1 client then I was able to connect even with 3 client in parallel and all were able to communicate with the server.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The backlog parameter can be adjusted up or down by the platform. The actual minimum backlog was initially 5 in BSD 4.3 and it is now more like 50 or even 500 on some platforms. There is no API to determine the actual value used.

Comment: So does it mean that this contructor of `ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)` is really of no better than `ServerSocket(int port)` because `backlog` JVM cannot determine the number of request that can queue on the listening port??

Comment: It means what I said, and the part after 'because' is a *non sequitur*.