# Python TCP server: serves client through different port than the listening port

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, webserver

I am writing a simple multi-threaded web server that receive client HTTP request and return either a simple html page or a 404 error.

One of the requirement is

> You can implement this with your main thread listening for clients at a fixed port. When your server receives a TCP connection request from a client, the TCP connection to serve the client should happen through another port

Wouldn't TCP connection serve the client throught the same port via different socket (i.e. tuple of (server IP:server port, client IP:client port)?

I found little information online on how to listen to client request on one port (e.g. port 80) and serve the request on another port (e.g. port 1234). Any direction or recommendation on how to achieve this? I need to do this in Python.

Thank you for your thoughts.

edit: typo and tags

Comment: That requirement doesn't make any sense. Servers can always serve on the same port to multiple clients. Is it the whole problem description? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997754/does-the-port-change-when-a-server-accepts-a-tcp-connection) as an example.

Comment: Thank you @Selcuk. That's basically the whole problem description. The problem also mentions the server needs to be "a multi-threaded version" and "Each TCP connection requested is handled in a separate thread", which is standard operation I think.

Comment: While this is possible in theory. It would require OS level modifications to work, which makes it very impractical. It is just not how TCP should work. Much more likely is that the person writing the requirements was not so aware of the technical detail or expressed the requirement badly.

Comment: @tz35 It doesn't have to be multi threaded (think thousands of clients hitting a popular web server at the same time. It is not practical to have that many threads) but obviously the assignment asks for it. The "another port" part looks like a misunderstanding, though. Maybe they meant the client port (which is randomly chosen from a pool of ports)?

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but one possibility would be to have a smart protocol where the client first asks for a port number by first connecting to the server using a fixed, known port; then disconnects and makes a new connection to the new port number previously provided by the server. Port knocking works in a similar fashion but I'm not sure what would be the practical use of this method for a general purpose TCP server.

Comment: so in this case, the server will need to create a another port at pre-specified port number (i.e. the number sent to the client in previous connection) and will be listening on that port until the client make a second connection?